# How can I set the modifed date of certain content?

Tags: alfresco

I need to change the date that Alfresco shows in the content detail. Every time I change something about properties or tags, the modified date updates to that time. That is great so far.

Problem: I need to make some changes on some uploaded files without updating that date. Some of them have their modified date changed already.

If I could set in mysql the date I wanted, then everything would be great, but if I set the audit_created and audit_modified fields in alf_node table, the change seems to affect only to the list view, but it does not changes dates in the detail view.

I've tried several workarounds of my own, but none of them has worked. Could somebody give me a hint on how to get this done?

Thanks.

Alfresco Community - v3.2.0

Comment: Your original approach would work with index reindex, I believe. The behaviour filter is the way to go, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to you all. Rebuilding the index is what actually worked for me. @Lista, I would accept your comment as answer if I knew how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about version 3.2 (*caugh*), but I guess

```java
behaviourFilter.disableBehaviour(nodeRef, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
```

should do the trick. Also not quite sure at what event the behavior fires. Call this method right before you change properties.

Comment: And enable the behaviour again after you code has finised. You can use a `try`/`finally` block for this.

Comment: I was modifyng the content as an user would, so I had not planned writing a whole script for that. Anyway, messing with the auditable aspect in the DB may result in something useful... I'll run more tests on Monday. Thanks for the tip, and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Disabling the behavior like shown only applies for that one node and won't last beyond the scope of the current transaction. Hence, there most likely won't be a need to enable the behavior again.